# ¿Fallo en la foreing key al escribir el nombre?

Tags: mysql

Por alguna razón que desconozco esta **foreignkey** me peta, según tengo entendido es porque los nombres no coinciden pero yo no lo veo, estoy trabajando en workbench. Esta es mi lista de tablas

```
Create table Galaxia(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre VARCHAR(20),
Distancia_años_luz INT(19),
Extension_Elevado INT(9),
ID_Galaxia INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);

Create table Estrella(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre VARCHAR(20),
Tipo_de_tamaño VARCHAR(30),
Color VARCHAR(10),
ID_Estrella INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);


Create table G_E(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_Galaxia INT(4),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Galaxia) REFERENCES Galaxia(ID_Galaxia)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ID_Estrella INT(4),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID_Estrella)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);


Create table Constelacion(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre VARCHAR(20),
Numero_estrellas INT(4),
Extension INT(4),
ID_Constelacion INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);


Create table Con_es(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_Constelacion INT(4),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Constelacion) REFERENCES Constelacion(ID_Constelacion),
ID_Estrella INT(4),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID_Estrella),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);


Create table Planeta(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre VARCHAR(20),
ZonaH BIT,
Luna BIT,
ID_Planeta INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);

Create table Es_pla(
ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_Planeta INT(4),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Planeta) REFERENCES Planeta(ID_Planeta),
ID_Estrella INT(4),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID_Estrella),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion)
);
```

Comment: cuál es exactamente la foreign key que te da problemas?

Comment: por ejemplo al intentar crear la tabla G_Eme da este fallo:














10:07:44 Create table G_E( ID_Identificacion INT AUTO_INCREMENT, ID_Galaxia INT(4), FOREIGN KEY(ID_Galaxia) REFERENCES Galaxia(ID_Galaxia) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, ID_Estrella INT(4), FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID_Estrella) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY (ID_Identificacion) ) Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `universo`.`g_e` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 0.375 sec

Comment: Hola. El problema está en que estás intentando hacer un foreign key de un campo que puede no ser unico (UNIQUE) en la tabla principal. Normalmente las Foreign Keys se enlazan con ids de tablas que son únicos y auto-incrementales.

Comment: Ni idea de como arreglar eso

Comment: Por ejemplo, desconozco la finalidad y el porqué está así la estructura, pero no me parece lógico tener un ID_Identificacion y un Id_Galaxia en la tabla "Galaxia"... En principio, una Galaxia debería ser única, con lo que, el Id_Identificacion que tienes (que yo pondría "Id" a secas) debería bastar.

Answer (score 2):

Como te decia en los comentarios, el problema es que querías hacer una Foreign Key de un campo que no es Unique, y esto por definición, es imposible. Además, tienes campos redundantes en la estructura de la tabla, haciendo que a la hora de crear las tablas y las posteriores relaciones, pues tengas problemas.

Por ejemplo, no entiendo la existencia de un Id_Identificacion y un Id_NombreTabla (por ejemplo, Id_Galaxia en la tabla "Galaxia" o Id_Estrella en la tabla "Estrella"). No, **el Id es y debe ser un campo único**, con lo que, para las foreign keys utiliza el campo de la Primary Key.

Te he eliminado estos campos redundantes y modificado el nombre del Id principal (llamandolo Id a secas), luego he montado las foreign keys y todo el proceso me ha funcionado correctamente.

```
Create table Galaxia(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre VARCHAR(20), 
    Distancia_años_luz INT, 
    Extension_Elevado INT);

Create table Estrella(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre VARCHAR(20), 
    Tipo_de_tamaño VARCHAR(30), 
    Color VARCHAR(10));

Create table G_E(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ID_Galaxia INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ID_Galaxia
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Galaxia) REFERENCES Galaxia(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    ID_Estrella INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE);

Create table Constelacion(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre VARCHAR(20), 
    Numero_estrellas INT, 
    Extension INT);

Create table Con_es(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ID_Constelacion INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Constelacion) REFERENCES Constelacion(ID), 
    ID_Estrella INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID));

Create table Planeta(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre VARCHAR(20), 
    ZonaH BIT, 
    Luna BIT);

Create table Es_pla(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ID_Planeta INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Planeta) REFERENCES Planeta(ID), 
    ID_Estrella INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Estrella) REFERENCES Estrella(ID));
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias ya lo arregle

Comment: Muchas gracias por el feedback. De nada ;)

Comment: @user155885 considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si la misma ha resuelto tu problema. Saludos.